# Monitor APIs with Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm just getting started with Nagios and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a plugin or built-in function that would allow me to monitor restful APIs?

I want to be able to run a predefined GET/POST methods to endpoints and check that they don't return an error.

Comment: See https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to parse JSON output or the like, **check_http**, bundled in Nagios Core, could be the right tool for the job.

It has SNI support, HTTP methods, PKI certificates support, headers string check, response string/regex check.

Just give a look to all the switches invoking `check_http -h`.

Comment: I can at least get the status code with `check_http`?

Comment: Yes. See ryekayo's commend on your original post. It would be worth your while reading up on the module and what it can do.